# How to disable a member function based on a class template parameter?

Tags: c++, class, templates, sfinae

To illustrate the situation, let's assume a minimal example: a `Vector` template class taking its dimension as a non-type template parameter. This class will provide `x()`, `y()` (etc.) accessors when the dimension allows it:

```
template <int N_dimension>
class Vector
{
public:
    // ctors, etc.    
    int &x();

    template <class = std::enable_if_t<(N_dimension>2)>> int &y();

private:
    std::array<int, N_dimension> mData;
};
```

Yet, this does not work, because `enable_if` can only be applied on **deduced** template parameters.

Our current workaround looks cumbersome:

```
    template <int N=N_dimension, class = std::enable_if_t<(N>2)>> int &y();
```

Moreover, it also requires a static-assert in the definition to make sure it is fool-proof (because now client code could give an explicit value to `N` that does not match the real dimension. **Edit**: Or an explicit value for the anonymous second template parameter, as pointed out by *SergeyA*).

---

Is there a more direct approach to express this in C++?

Comment: Specialization is the only other option. But the "cumbersome" option is really not that much; and I wouldn't worry about someone specifying an explicit template parameter.  This is what comments and documentation is for. Put a comment that says: do not specify any parameters, leave them alone.

Comment: You have another flaw as well - by giving explicit type as a second template parameter client can also instantiate the function. Since you do not seem to specifically enable other `y()` in case where `N_dimension` is greater the 2, why do you need it at all? Just leave `static_assert` which is way more descriptive than lines and lines of template subsitution errors.

Answer (score 4):

In C++20, you might simply use `requires` to discard method:

```
template <int N>
class Vector
{
public:
    int &x();
    int &y() requires(N >= 2);

private:
    std::array<int, N_dimension> mData;
};
```

In previous version, it is more verbose:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class Vector
{
public:
    int &x();

    template <std::size_t M = N, std::enable_if_t<(M >= 2 && M == N), int> = 0>
    int &y();

private:
    std::array<int, N_dimension> mData;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do away with SFINAE here, and simply split the code into interface and private implementation like that:

```
int& y() {
    return y_impl(std::bool_constant<N > 2>{});
}

private:
int& y_impl(std::true_type ) {
    // impl
}
int& y_impl(std::false_type ) {
    static_assert(N > 2 /* always false */, "Wrong number of dimensions!");
}
```

The split here is in assumption of `y` not compilable when `N <= 2`, to reduce the clutter of error messages. If this is not the case, a single `static_assert` in `y` body would be sufficient.

Comment: A limitation with this approach is that the member function is not actually removed, making it impossible (to my knowledge) to test for its absence with mechanism such as [`is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)